# Agregar mas datos al Login PHP

Tags: php, login

Hola espero me puedan ayudar, estoy armando un login y tengo una base de datos con tres campos (USUARIO, CONTRASEÑA Y NOMBRE), hace la función correcta de validar los datos pero al iniciar agrega una impresión de linea que dice USUARIO: e imprime el dato del campo usuario, yo quisiera que aquí se imprimiera el dato  del campo Nombre. Por ejemplo mi USUARIO=Jorge, CONTRASEÑA=123 y NOMBRE=Jorge Ramirez, lo que busco es que al iniciar sesión que en vez decir USUARIO: Jorge diga lo almacenado en NOMBRE (USUARIO: Jorge Ramirez).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
 BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    h2{
    text-align: center;}
table{
    width: 25%;
    border: 2px dotted #F00;
    margin:auto;}
td{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10 px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
try {
$base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas','root','');
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios_pass WHERE USUARIOS=:login and PASSWORD=:password";
$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
$login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
$password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
$resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
$resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);
$resultado->execute();
$numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();
if($numero_registro!=0){
   session_start(); 
   $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];
}else{
    echo "ERROR DE DATOS";
}
}catch(Exception $e){
die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
include("form.php");
}else{
echo "Usuario: " . $_SESSION["usuario"];
}
?>
<h2>CONTENIDO WEB</h2>
<table width="800" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/1.jpg" widht="300" height="166"></td>
            <td><img src="images/2.jpg" widht="300" height="166"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/3.jpg" widht="300" height="166"></td>
            <td><img src="images/4.jpg" widht="300" height="166"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

`

GRACIAS

Comment: Muy bien creo que de nuestra parte no vemos inconveniente, puedes proceder a realizarlo, ahora bien si tienes alguna duda o problema favor de expresarlo al detalle. Asi como lo haz puesto parece que estas pidiendo permiso o que te hagan la tarea.

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario, no es forzoso que aportes. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Sería mejor si el usuario lo obtuvieras desde la misma consulta que retornas. Ando un poco oxidado con PHP pero te dejo un código que seguro entenderás bien y que te ayudará.

```
//verification.php
<?php 
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    //Llama al archivo que contiene la información a la base de datos
    require_once('../conn.php');

    $user = $_POST['lgn_mail'];
    $password = $_POST['lgn_pass'];

    //Si algún campo está vacío, redirecciona al login y envía parámetros
    if(empty($_POST['lgn_mail']) || empty($_POST['lgn_pass'])){
        header('Location: ../login.php?error=invalidpass');
    }else{

        //Genera una consulta
        $query= "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE mail = '{$user}' AND pass = '{$password}'";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

        //Si la consulta falló, retorna error
        if($result == FALSE){
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        //Si devuelve un registro vacío, no existe el usuario
        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
            header('Location: ../login.php?error=emptyresult');
        }else{

            //Busca la información correspondiente al usuario y los valores
            //son asignados a variables de sesión.
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
                $_SESSION['lgn_userName'] = $row['userName'];
                $_SESSION['lgn_id_identifier'] = $row['id_identifier'];
            }
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Y así consulto los valores de las variables de sesión

```
//index.php
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);

    //Si no hay una sesión activa, redirecciona, por lo contrario,
    //guarda el identificador y el usuario en nueva variables
    if (@!$_SESSION['lgn_userName']) {
        header("Location:login.php");
    }else{
        $id_identifier = $_SESSION['lgn_id_identifier'];
        $userName = $_SESSION['lgn_userName'];
    }
?>
```

Casi lo olvido, estoy usando SQL Server, pero la lógica sirve para tu base de datos. Saludos.